# Clementine cannot play online streams

Tags: clementine

I have installed all the gstreamer plugins by installing from ubuntu restricted extras.
But when i try to stream anything from any source last.fm or any other, it just shows the song info in the playlist and then without playing the song shows playlist finsished and clementine stopped.

The output in the terminal is this:

```
13:16:28.468 WARN  unknown                          QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2 
13:16:28.471 WARN  unknown                          QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2 
13:16:32.719 DEBUG unknown                          "sni-qt/3729" INFO  13:16:32.719 void StatusNotifierItem::slotAboutToShow() Adding an "Activate" entry to the StatusNotifierItem context menu  
13:17:19.919 WARN  unknown                          QTimeLine::start: already running 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                          "  <lfm status="ok"> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                              <nowplaying> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                                <track corrected="0">Maps. (Carvell Remix) Full Version!</track> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                                <artist corrected="0">Carvell</artist> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                                <album corrected="0"/> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                                <albumArtist corrected="0"/> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                                <ignoredMessage code="0"/> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                              </nowplaying> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                            </lfm> 
13:17:21.735 DEBUG unknown                          "
```

And i use a http proxy server behind authentication but i don't think that's the problem because i have entered the settings in clementine and the search feature does work fine.

Please help i have no idea what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Making Clementine *not* use the proxy made things work. I did that this way (Korn or Bourne Shell):

```
/bin/env HTTP_PROXY= HTTPS_PROXY= http_proxy= https_proxy= clementine
```

You can use a variant of this as part of a launcher to make it work properly.